# how to push view controller after changing tabbar controller selectedIndex together

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have six tabItem view controller, each child view controller has own a navigation controller itself. I have a problem to push a new view controller after changing the selectedIndex. I used AZTabBarController to create a tabbar variable.

```
//the viewcontroller I want to push
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateArticleViewController") as! CreateArticleViewController
//this can changing my tabbar selected index well.
self.currentTabBar?.setIndex(3, animated: true)
// Below code doesn't work
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
self.currentnavigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

tabcontroller -> Navigation 1 -> A1 -> A2

-> Navigation 2 -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> B4

-> Navigation 3 -> C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4

-> Navigation 4 -> D1 -> D2 -> D3 -> D4

-> Navigation 5 -> E1 -> E2 -> E3

-> Navigation 6 -> F1 -> F2 -> F3

For example, when I tapping a button in A1, how do I change the index and push the view controller to D3?
Should I use customize delegate to do this trick?
Please see snapshot for my storyboard.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Ycs.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `selectedIndex` the navigation you push in is for A not the new D so you need

```
self.currentTabBar!.setIndex(3, animated: true) 
let dNav = self.currentTabBar!.viewControllers[3] as! UINavigationController
dNav.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: It said "Value of type 'AZTabBarController' has no member 'viewControllers'". Am I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will allow you to immediately display the screen to the desired destination and return with the configured navigation controller(From anywhere).

tabcontroller -> Navigation 1 -> A1 -> A2

```
func moveToA2() {
   let a1VC = #(instantiate A1 View Controller)
   let a2VC = #(instantiate A2 View Controller)
   let rootVC = 
   UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? 
UITabBarController
   let navigationController = rootVC?.children[0] as? UINavigationController
   rootVC?.selectedIndex = 0
   navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
   navigationController?.pushViewController(a1VC, animated: false)
   navigationController?.pushViewController(a2VC, animated: false)
}
```

tabcontroller -> Navigation 2 -> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> B4

```
func moveTob4() {
    let b1VC = #(instantiate B1 View Controller)
    let b2VC = #(instantiate B2 View Controller)
    let b3VC = #(instantiate B3 View Controller)
    let b4VC = #(instantiate B4 View Controller)
    let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
    let navigationController = rootVC?.children[1] as? UINavigationController
    rootVC?.selectedIndex = 1
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(b1VC, animated: false)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(b2VC, animated: false)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(b3VC, animated: false)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(b4VC, animated: false)
}
```